# Combinatorial problem using generating functions

Tags: combinatorics

We have n euros. Every day we buy exactly one of the following products: pretzel (1 euro),
candy (2 euro), icecream (2 euros). What is the number of possible ways of spending all
the money (the order of the bought products counts)?

How we can solve this problem using generating function? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The meta thread [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) includes some advice which would improve this one. See in particular the sections Provide context and avoid "no-clue" questions.

Comment: What is the generating function for spending money only on pretzels? Candy? Ice cream? If you have those, you can ask yourself what operation on generating functions you know that has a particular combinatorial meaning that applies here.

Comment: Which generating function can I use? OGF or EGF? Or can we have another alternative methods that enable us to solve the problem?

Comment: You just want to count the strings of length $n$ over the alphabet $\Sigma=\{p,cc,ii\}$, and this can be easily done through (Fibonacci-like) recurrence relations. $L_n = L_{n-1}+2 L_{n-2}$ gives that $L_n = A(-1)^n+B\,2^n$ and you may apply interpolation to find $A$ and $B$.

Comment: If my computations are correct, in this case $L_n$ simply is the closest integer to $\frac{2}{3}2^n$.

Comment: Actually, what you did is nice but to understand it more what happens the recurrence relation you gave above if $\sum =\{p, cc, ii, ss, bb, rr, kkk, www,  ddd\}$?

Comment: If you have two ordinary generating functions, do you know what the combinatorial meaning of the product is?

Comment: I am not sure. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

If $k$ is the number of days and $n$ the number of euros, the number of possibilities is :

$$\binom {k}{n-k} 2^{n-k}$$

The generating function for one day is:

$$Oneday = e + e^2 + e^2$$

meaning that there is one way to spend one euro and two ways to spent two euros.

$k$ days will be described by :

$$Oneday^k = (e + e^2 + e^2)^k$$

that gives the coefficients

$1, 2$

$0, 1, 4, 4$

$0, 0, 1, 6, \bbox[border:1px solid green] {12}, 8$

$0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 24, 32, 16$

where, for example, $12$ stands for the number of ways to spend 5 euros in 3 days.

Examining the computed numbers for small $k$ and $n$'s, the pattern occurs.

In $k$ days we can spend $k...2k$ euros. If we spends $k+l$ this is because in some $l$ days we buy $l$ expensive candies. These candies may be one of two types.

The sum for fixed $k$ is $3^k$.

The sum for fixed $n$ is "Jacobsthal number" : see https://oeis.org/A001045 .

$0, 1, 1, 3, 5, 11, 21, 43, 85, 171...$

The recurrence $a_n = a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2}$ is nice and simple to explain.

Exponential generating functions are not directly useful for identical objects, but for distinct, labeled objects, because passing from labeled to unlabeled is a difficult procedure.